# Importrange + query formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Can anyone help? I'm trying to create a separate sheet that would automatically import the data from this source sheet below using importrange and query formula.

[source sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzrSF.png)

I want to import specific column (columns A, E & F) data only if the column G is equal to "EUR". Here's my formula but it's not working for me.

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("this is where i put my source sheet URL","All Orders!A2:G1000")"select=col1,col5,col6 where col7=EUR") )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("this is where i put my source sheet URL","All Orders!A2:G1000"),"SELECT Col1, Col5, Col6 WHERE Col7='EUR'") )
```

Col is case sensitive and when you are comparing to a string you need to wrap it in single quotes.